# What is "/**/*" for files in package.json for react/electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am trying to create binary for a react electron application and I came across with this in package.json. What does `**/*` mean ?

```
   "build": {
    "appId": "com.com.com",
    "productName": "Prost",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "public/**/*",
      "src/images/**/*"
    ]
  },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `**` means any directory - including sub directories.

The `*` Means any file.

so `src/**/*` means any file in any directory inside the `src` directory.

Answer (score 4):

- `dir/*` - all files in directory,
- `dir/*/*` - all files in directory
  and nested directories (1 level deep),
- `dir/**/*` - all files in
  directory and all subdirectories.